# Error while reading RTF file in Java

Tags: java, rtf

while reading the contents from an RTF file and converting it into String format . I am getting the following exception .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:572)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFParser.write(RTFParser.java:249)
at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFParser.write(RTFParser.java:135)
at javax.swing.text.rtf.AbstractFilter.write(AbstractFilter.java:173)
at javax.swing.text.rtf.AbstractFilter.readFromStream(AbstractFilter.java:106)
at javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit.read(RTFEditorKit.java:82)
at com.coseer.whatsapp.CoseerProject.FetcherData.convertFileToString(FetcherData.java:57)
```

The code is :

```
RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
    Document doc = rtf.createDefaultDocument();
String sa="";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
    try {
        rtf.read(fis,doc,0);
          sa=doc.getText(0,doc.getLength());
          System.out.println(sa);
            return sa;
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
```

I am getting an exception on : rtf.read(fis,doc,0);

Comment: The error says that it's trying to read a number and seeing a "-" instead. I don't think there are many parsers that can read a "-" and get a number out of it. If you catch the NumberFormatException, you can make it NaN (Not-a-Number) or 0, depending on your needs.

Comment: i am not tryiing to get a number out of it , i am just inputting a rtf file , and want a String in return

Comment: Are you sure it's a valid RTF file?

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid rtf document (do you get the same problem with other docs)? What version of Java are you using?  @rajah9 - catching the NumberFormatException won't do any good since it's the Java-provided document parser that is choking.

Comment: have 20 rtf files to process, i get the same error in some files , others i dont get .Mostly i get errors. Java version is 1.8.  How to check whether it is valid rtf file or not

Comment: Go look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format and see if your file looks like it matches.  That'll at least tell you if it's _close_ to valid RTF or something else altogether.

Comment: Can you try reading the files using RTFParserKit? https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit you may find it handles RTF better than RTFEditorKit.

Comment: Have somebody solved it? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Can you add an example RTF? (Just a few lines around the location which contains the minus sign)